# Left-recursive grammars in operator precedence parsing

Tags: f#, fparsec

I have a left recursive grammar. My AST looks something like:

```ml
...
and Expr = BinaryExpr of BinaryExpr
and BinaryExpr = Expr * BinaryOperator * Expr
and BinaryOperator = Plus
...
```

I was planning on using the operator precedence parser for this, for example:

```ml
let exprOpp = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<Expr,unit,unit>()
let pBinaryExpr = exprOpp.ExpressionParser
exprOpp.TermParser <- pExpr

let consBinExpr op x y = (x, op, y) |> BinaryExpr
exprOpp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("+", ws, 1, Associativity.Left, (consBinExpr Plus)))
```

where `pExpr` is a parser for `Expr`.

The left recursion causes a stack overflow. I was wondering whether there was a particular FParsec-way of dealing with this while still using the `OperatorPrecedenceParser`?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The issue may be coming from the fact that `pExpr` forwards all calls to another parser `pExprRef`.

```ml
let pExpr, pExprRef = createParserForwardedToRef()
```

and after the operator precedence parser, the reference is defined:

```ml
do pExprRef :=
    choice [pBinaryExpr, <other-parsers...>];
```

Comment: Your example would never terminate; you'd need another option in `Expr` that represents a single value. As it is, your example types are infinitely recursive.

Comment: Thanks. I also got rid of the `createParserForwardedToRef` as it seems `pExpr` forwards all calls to the `TermParser`